# How to move between two activity with an action?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I want to move of one activity to another activity with an action. I mean when to show second activity, first activity slow move and of right to left move and exit of page and second activity, shows of right to left shows in the page. 
I googled but i can't find this, maybe for this i don't know what should i search!

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for advises.

Cheers

Comment: means do you want to show animation between two activities??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up animations (like slide) when you switch between activities like this :
In the res folder, create an anim folder
 For example, put two xml files for a slide effect :

slide_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="200"/>
  </set>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="200" />
    </set>
```

Then on your java code just write this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

If you are testing that on a real device, don't forget to allow it to play animations (Settings -> Display -> Animations -> All Animation)

Hope it helps !:)

Comment: Thanks for answer.Do i set animation when i use FrameLayout? I have a FrameLayout and i use Fragment and FragmentActivity for change activity.